# getting data directly from insert query after running it

Tags: mysql

i have a database i insert item into using php. i want to get the ID which is auto increment column, i read the manual and it says that the mysql_query returns a resource variable rather than boolean, is there any way to retreive data from that resouce?

```
echo $query_ins = "INSERT INTO `house` VALUES ('' , '$city', '$street', 'num');
$res = mysql_query($query_ins);
```

the first field is the ID field i am interested in.
i tried mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_result function to convert the $res into array or retrieve data directly like i would do with SELECT query but no succes.
any suggestions?

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated. You should be using PDO, or at the least, mysqli.

Comment: from the insert statement you can just get the last insert id. for more data, you need to run a select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the manual: [mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

This is really something you should have been able to find on your own easily, without posting to StackOverflow.  It's to your advantage to review the documentation of any API you're using.

---

Re your comment:

```
SELECT * FROM house WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

This supposes you have an auto-incrementing primary key.

If you generate a nondeterministic primary key value on insert, for example using RAND() or UUID(), then there is effectively no way to retrieve the value generated.  You should generate the value before doing the INSERT, so you have a literal value you can use to look up the row.

```
SET @r := RAND();
INSERT INTO house (id, ...) VALUES (@r, ...);
SELECT * FROM house WHERE id = @r;
```

MD5 is deterministic, so supposing you have an original key string that you hash, you should be able to retrieve the row using that MD5 expression and the original string.

```
INSERT INTO house (id, ...) VALUES (MD5('xyzzy'), ...);
SELECT * FROM house WHERE id = MD5('xyzzy');
```

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer, in this case the id was really what i wanted but in general is there any way to retrieve data from that resource? lets say i have a random field or a MD5 code generated when i insert data

Comment: Hey bill, I've seen some using `@` in PHP as well as SQL, any special meaning? I guess in PHP it prevents warnings?

Comment: The `@` operator suppresses errors in PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php  It's not generally considered good practice to suppress errors.  You should solve the root cause of the error, not sweep it under the carpet.

Comment: The `@` in MySQL has a different and unrelated meaning.  It prefixes user-defined session variables.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you for your answer it is very helpfull, so if i get it correctly the resource that the mysql_query function returns has no info in it?

Comment: For INSERT, the mysql_query function only returns TRUE or FALSE, indicating that the insert was successful or an error occurred.  No resource is returned when you execute INSERT.